# Why do some people put the value before variable in if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, comparison

For example, what's different from $variable === true?

```
<?php

if (true === $variable) {
     //
}

if (1 === intval($variable)) {
    //
}
```

Comment: Because they saw someone do it once, and they don't know how to think for themselves.

Comment: Don't do this. It is "The Wrong Thing To Do".

Comment: The answers about doing it for safety are valid, but I know there is also people who do it just because it's harder to read. I usually find those kinds of "if" statements in unnecessarily hard to read code.

Comment: Anyway, nowadays it's a moot point, since most good IDEs will warn you when assigning a variable inside an "if" statement (in some quite rare cases assignments inside "if" can be actually useful if you know what you're doing -that's how I found out about these warnings- although I guess some people would also classify that into the "unnecessarily hard to read code" category, but in those rare cases I always add a comment saying that the assignment in the "if" is intentional, just in case someone sees the code, notices the warning, and thinks it might be an error).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are equivalent.

Some programmers prefer this "Yoda style" in order to avoid the risk of accidentally writing:

```
if ($variable = true) {
    // ...
}
```

, which is equivalent to

```
$variable = true;
// ...
```

, when they meant to write

```
if ($variable === true) {
    // ...
}
```

(whereas `if (true = $variable)` would generate an obvious error rather than a potentially-subtle bug).

Comment: Note, `1 === intval($variable)` confers no benefit whatsoever.  The return value can't be assigned to, so `intval($variable) = 1` will fail the same way.

Comment: @cHao: The OP gave two examples. `true === $variable` is for the reason I said. `1 === intval($variable)` is for consistency: if you have a certain pattern that is safer in some cases, then you should stick with it in all cases, because otherwise you'll miss it even when you need it. (That said, I find Yoda style too ugly. There are better ways to accomplish this goal.)

Answer (score 12):

**Short answer**

Some people do it in order to avoid mistakenly using the assignment operator (`=`) when they really meant to use a comparison operator (`==` or `===`).

**Long answer**

In PHP there are 3 operators that can be mistaken for eachother:

- `=` is the assignment operator
- `==` is the "equal to" operator
- `===` is the "identical to" operator

The first operator is only used for assigning a value to a variable. The second and third are only used for comparing two values, or expressions, against eachother.

In PHP it is possible to assign a value to a variable inside control structures (`if`, `for`, `while`, etc.). This may cause problems if you are not careful. For example, if you want to compare `$a` against a boolean value you can do it like this:

```
if ($a == false) // or
if ($a === false)
```

If you are not careful, however, it may end up like this:

```
if ($a = false)
```

... which is perfectly legal code, but it is an assignment and will eventually cause problems. The reason it will cause problems is because the expression, `$a=false`, will be evaluated and the code will keep running as if nothing is wrong, when in fact it was not intended.

The reason some people switch around the operands, when comparing a value against a literal (fixed value, like `true`, `false`, `7`, `5.2`, and so on), is because it is not possible to assign a value to a literal. For example:

```
if (false = $a)
```

... will cause an error, telling the programmer that they made a mistake, which they can then fix.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is just the way of thinking in general. When you really think about a deep if statement, you think if that statement is true, not the other point of view. It's not wrong, but in my head naming it inverse, would annoy me and make me lose concentration about the statement. So I would say it's just the way people think :D.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between `($var === true)` and `(true === $var)`. They are equivalent.

See http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php for a complete table of comparisons. You'll see that all equivalent comparisons have the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Also, some people do prefer to see what's the result which is been evaluated before the statement.
Some statements might be longer and harder to read.

Ex:

```
if (false == (new DataParser()->makeAComplexDataParser((new SomeTransformer()->doTransformation((new someClass()->getMethodOfLongParameters($param1, $param2, (new Date()->format('Y-m-d'))))))))  ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

So it's better to think "is it false this complex expression?" instead of thinking 
"this looooooooonger complex expression is....hmmmm....false?"

Comment: Actually, when you have a situation like this you need to put the "loooooong complex expression" inside a variable and check that in the if, but that's not question related